# UnityEngine.UI outside of Unity Environment

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to compile several scripts in my project into an easier to move and manage DLL file, however several scripts call UnityEngine.UI, and I know that the DLL file used to exist in `/Contents/UnityExtensions/Unity/GUISystem/Editor/UnityEditor.UI.dll` however the only data I can find for it now are the uncompiled files inside the Package Manager, where is the compiled DLL stored now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer that I just found is to look in the project folder of one of your projects in `Library\ScriptAssemblies`